# How to update a single commit on a Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, will-paginate

I've installed `will_paginate` with Gem and Bundle; now I see there's an update on GitHub ([this commit](https://github.com/dhh/will_paginate/commit/1814f5a3439333212a4e20cd4fa9db2f394fbf91)) -- How can I update it? Manually? Reinstall it with `git clone`?

Comment: this commit was in Jan 010 though... if you just installed will_paginate in a rails 3 or bundle'd capacity, chances are it's in there already, is it not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `bundle update`

You can add the gem name if you want to update a specific one with `bundle update will_paginate`

Here's a more detailed tutorial: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

You want the subsection called "Updating a Gem Without Modifying the Gemfile".

If you have included the gem in the Gemfile with a git path (and you haven't included any directive that would prevent an update like a version number), it will update the gem based on the source provided. You'll need to do this everywhere. Updates are not synchronized with your application's version control.

---

Here is a guide specific to git: http://gembundler.com/git.html

If you only want a specific commit, you're going to need to add a `:ref` argument with the hash.

Answer (score 2):

run

```
bundle update will_paginate
```